# How to print 2 values at once with selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I hope everyone is having a good day. I am trying to extract values from a website and have them print out as a list, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have all the values printing as expecting, just can't figure out how to have them print one after another. I know this is a very basic question, but I can't figure it out. Any advice or information is appreciated! Thank you!

```
import time
import webbrowser
from os import O_SEQUENTIAL, link
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

webdriver = wd.Chrome(executable_path= r"C:\Users\Stephanie\anaconda3\pkgs\python-chromedriver-binary-98.0.4758.48.0-py39hcbf5309_0\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver_binary\chromedriver.exe")
webdriver.implicitly_wait(1)
webdriver.maximize_window()

webdriver.get("https://pcpartpicker.com/user/stephwaters/saved/#view=HgH2xr")
time.sleep(2)

partname = webdriver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'td__component')
for part in partname:
    print(part.text + ': ')


prices = webdriver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'td__price')
for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

This is the output:
[image: Output]

I would like it to print:
Case: $168.99
Power Supply: $182.00

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the `partnames` and `prices` separately you can iterate over a list of products extracting from each one it's name and price.
Also it's recommended to use Expected Conditions explicit waits, not a hardcoded pauses.
Your code could be something like this:

```py
import time
import webbrowser
from os import O_SEQUENTIAL, link
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

webdriver = wd.Chrome(executable_path= r"C:\Users\Stephanie\anaconda3\pkgs\python-chromedriver-binary-98.0.4758.48.0-py39hcbf5309_0\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver_binary\chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20)
webdriver.maximize_window()

webdriver.get("https://pcpartpicker.com/user/stephwaters/saved/#view=HgH2xr")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='tr__product']")))
time.sleep(0.3) #short delay added to make sure not the first product only got loaded
products = = webdriver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tr[@class="tr__product"]')
for product in products:
    name = product.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[@class="td__component"]')
    price = product.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[@class="td__price"]//a') 
    print(name.text + ': ' + price.text)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! This worked great, all I had to add at the end was:

except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No price")

to skip over the ones that did have a price, and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help!!